# how to develop a HTTP web filter in java

Tags: java, jsp, http, proxy, http-proxy

I want to develop an application to filter some HTTP traffic and block some specific sites,
I don't know how can I do it ,
I though that I can develop this app. with JSP , But now I think I should use a proxy to develop ,
I want my app to recognize the HTTP packets and then check a file (a black list of sites ) and filter the matching URLs by not showing the site content to user  .
can any body help me and explain how can I develop this app?

PS: sorry for my English! =)

Comment: sounds like you want to write a proxy server

Answer (score -1):

You may write a Java servlet. Servlets are good filters. See tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html and http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial for examples.

Comment: I think Servlet filters can  intercept HTTP requests targeted at my "web application" and I want to filter Urls and websites in my browser! Can my app with Servlet interact with the browser and filter requests and responses targeted at my browser ?
(I think my app should work between the request from my browser and arrived responses. is it right?)